# Resolving a Limit

Tags: limits

I'm studying for college exams and I don't know how to solve this type of limit:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -3} \sqrt{\frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}}
\end{align}$$

Any help?

**Update**: I know that the solution is:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{30}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Factorize and use "Limit of the square root is square root of the limit".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a polynomial has $-3$ as a root, then $x+3$ can always be factored out:

$$\lim_{x\to-3}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}}=\lim_{x\to-3}\sqrt{\frac{(x+3)(x-3)}{(x+3)(2 x+1)}}=\lim_{x\to-3}\sqrt{\frac{x-3}{2x+1}}=\sqrt\frac{-6}{-5}=\sqrt\frac65$$

Answer (score 5):

We have by the L'Hôpital theorem:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -3} \frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}=\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{2x}{4x+7}=\frac{6}{5}\end{align}$$

Notice that
$$\lim_{x\to -3}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}}}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}}\quad\text{Why?}$$

Comment: I still didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: You didn't get what?

Comment: My guess is that (s)he hasn't covered L'Hospital yet.

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes, that's true.

Comment: Fortunately for you there is  other answer without l'Hospital:-) @NunoBatalha

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**.  The obvious first try is to substitute $x=-3$ into the expression under the square root sign.  If you do this you get $\frac{0}{0}$.  Now of course $\frac{0}{0}$ is meaningless, so it does not answer the question.  Nevertheless it *does* tell you something about the polynomials $x^2-9$ and $2x^2+7x+3$.  What?

Answer (score 3):

Try factoring both the numerator and the denominator.